# Box-shadow over horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css

I use box shadow to give the impression my div #collection-content is located below the other parts of the page. However, while its vertical scrollbar places itself under the shadow correctly (se green circle on the picture below), the horizontal scrollbar doesn't (see red circle) and I don't get why.

I tried to fiddle with z-index and the only way I can make it work is by setting #collection-content's z-index to -1, but that renders it unselectable (don't know if it's the normal behaviour?). Any other values on #collection-content and #side-panel (he one with the dysfunctional shadow) doesn't work.

I can't post the code here or create a fiddle cause there's just too much code. So if anyone has a wild guess I would appreciate it.

One thing that's weird is that I have set only overflow-y: scroll on #collection-content and the horizontal scrollbar still appears (as if it was overflow: auto, so, normal behaviour) but when I delete overflow-y: scroll, then the horizontal scrollbar also disappear and I don't feel like it's normal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does the sidebar have a position, relative, fixed or absolute? 
Without a position, the z-index could have no effect.

Comment: It's not inset, it's the external box-shadow of #side-panel

Answer (score 0):

you should try to nullify styles

add this to your css

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


ul[class],
ol[class] {
  padding: 0;
}


body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
ul[class],
ol[class],
li,
figure,
figcaption,
blockquote,
dl,
dd {
  margin: 0;
}


body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  line-height: 1.5;
}


ul[class],
ol[class] {
  list-style: none;
}


a:not([class]) {
  text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
}


img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}


article > * + * {
  margin-top: 1em;
}


input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}


@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  * {
    animation-duration: 0.01ms !important;
    animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
    transition-duration: 0.01ms !important;
    scroll-behavior: auto !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by simply using the following CSS code, I hope it can be useful:

```
padding: 30px 0;
margin: -30px 0;
```

basically padding is used on the container to show the shadow off and then a negative margin is immediately added to visually return the blocks to the same position as before.